# How to use arithmetic shift & selector in verilog?

Tags: math, verilog, bit-shift, shift

I want to use selector and arithmetic shift together.
But this code is failed to implemented, the result is just logical shift.

```
module multiplier(x1, x2, x1x2);
input [15:0] x1, x2;
output [15:0] x1x2;
assign x1x2 = 
x2[13]? ($signed(x1)>>>4'd1) : 16'b0000000000000000;
endmodule
```

The arithmetic shift is done successfull without selector like this code.

```
module multiplier(x1, x2, x1x2);
input [15:0] x1, x2;
output [15:0] x1x2;
assign x1x2 = $signed(x1)>>>4'd1;
endmodule
```

How to use selector and arithmetic shift together?

Comment: Might have to do with the fact the literal 16'b0 is unsigned; does it work if you make it a signed literal? (16'sb0)

Answer (score 2):

Verilog will almost always choose unsigned when it has a choice and it appears the selector logic is allowing Verilog to choose.

There are a couple if difference solutions:

- Use two lines:

  ```
  wire [15:0] x1_shift = $signed(x1)>>>4'd1;
  assign x1x2 = x2[13] ? x1_shift : 16'b0;
  ```
- Use Curly instead of parenthesis:

  ```
  assign x1x2 = x2[13]? { $signed(x1)>>>4'd1 } : 16'b0;
  ```
- Hard coded shift:

  ```
  assign x1x2 = x2[13] ? {x1[15],x1[15:1]} : 16'b0;
  ```
- Sign all conditions: (As Unn pointed out `16'b0` is unsigned)

  ```
  assign x1x2 = x2[13] ? ($signed(x1)>>>4'd1) : $signed(16'b0); // least recommenced
  ```
- With SystemVerilog you can also do size casting:

  ```
  assign x1x2 = x2[13] ? 16'($signed(x1)>>>4'd1) : 16'b0; // SV only, not Verilog
  ```

Working examples [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Aj8).